# IMPORTRANGE with MAX

Tags: google-sheets, max, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to IMPORTRANGE with MAX but just can't get it to work.

```
      Column A                 Column!M       Column!N
    1  apple                1   apple           5
    2  banana               2   apple           14
                            3   banana          10
                            4   apple           6
                            5   banana          8
```

Desired output:

```
  apple    14
  banana   10
```

This is what I have:

```
=MAX(importrange("url","Column!N1:N5"),importrange("url","Column!M1:M5")=A1:A2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

Cell B1, enter the following:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(MAX(if((importrange("SheetURL","SheetNameFromWhereYou’reImporting!M1:M5") = A1), (importrange("SheetURL","SheetNameFromWhereYou’reImporting!N1:N5")))))
```

Cell B2, enter the following:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(MAX(if((importrange("SheetURL","SheetNameFromWhereYou’reImporting!M1:M5") = A2), (importrange("SheetURL","SheetNameFromWhereYou’reImporting!N1:N5")))))
```